# Vue component undefined property when used as child for slot

Tags: pagination, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm just getting started with Vue Components and ran into an error that I can't seem to understand whats wrong.

I created a basic component that is almost identical to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html except instead of passing a data prop, I used a slot inside of the  tag. [Here is a gist of that full component](https://gist.github.com/jchamb/15cca4829ab7b36b1dd9aa00ec2fad82)

In a parent component I'm trying to combine my above table component and [vue-paginate](https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate) to output a paginated table.

```
<data-table>
    <paginate
        ref="paginator"
        name="urls"
        tag="tbody"
        class="data-table-body"
        :list="fUrls"
        :per="100"
    >
        <template v-for="url in paginated('urls')">
            <conversion-row :url="url"></conversion-row>
        </template>
    </paginate>
</data-table>
```

I removed the props on data table for brevity.

When using the above. I get an error of undefined urls. [Screen shot of Full Error Stack](http://take.ms/0PPyW)

This only happens when the paginate component is a child of my component. If I remove my data-table component then it is fine and i see the rows render. I know I must be missing something to make this all work. Reading through the guide I got the sense that because components are rendered in the parent scope that the paginate would render first and then replace the slot. However it seems like that isn't the case.

Can anyone provide some insights on why this doesn't work and an example of the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I think your problem is in `<template v-for="url in paginated('urls')">` vue can't find `urls` could you share the full source of where this code is?

Comment: @Saad I'm pretty sure that the undefined comes from paginate not being defined on the parent. In the vue-paginate script its failing on undefined on an if check  "if (!this.$parent.paginate[this.name]) {" Vue dev tools shows it like this. http://take.ms/cSf6T where paginate is a child of DataTable.  I was originally trying to make the inter body as flexible as possible, but i think i'm just gonna move the paginate within the DataTable component which should resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rearranging this and using scoped slots, to hoist my paginated data back up to my parent view.

In my DataTable (child) component I have

```
...
<paginate
    v-if="! isLoading"
    ref="paginator"
    name="data"
    tag="tbody"
    class="data-table-body"
    :list="data"
    :per="100"
>
    <slot :data="paginated('data')"></slot>
</paginate>
...
```

then in my parent template

```
<data-table :data="src">
    <template scope="dt">
        <conversion-row v-for="url in dt.data" :url="url"></conversion-row>
    </template>
</data-table>
```

This lets me pass in the full data src but loop through the paginated rows in my parent providing a custom body.

This might not be the best/most efficient way to do it but it works for my use case. If anyone has recommendations for improvement i'd love to hear.